# Eliminar campos con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero quitar campo por campo pero me quita todos los campos y bloquea agregar

```js
var nextinput = 0;

function AgregarCampos() {
  nextinput++;
  var campo = '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4"><p><input type="text"  class="form-control" \n\
    id="campo" name="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" /></p></div> <div class="col-xs-4"><input \n\
    type="text"  class="form-control"  id="campo" name="valores" placeholder="Ingrese el valor" /></div>';
  var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
  removeButton.click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
  $("#campos").append(campo);
  $("#campos").append(removeButton);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input onclick="AgregarCampos();" type="button" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-primary" />
</p>
<div id="campos">
</div>
```

Comment: si cada vez que des click en agregar  se agregan lo dos input pero al mometo que quero  eliminar campo por campo me elimina todos y me bloquea el boton agregar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola el problema ocurre que borra todo porque el div que contiene el boton que definiste termina afuera del div contenedor de los input, por lo que la solucion solo es reorganizar los divs.

Estabas incrustando html de esta forma. por eso el problema

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-5"> 
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="campo" name="valores" placeholder="Ingrese el valor" />
        </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <button type="button">-</button>
</div>
```

la forma correcta

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-5"> 
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="campo" name="valores" placeholder="Ingrese el valor" />
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button type="button">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui la solucion funcionando, aunque cambie un par de cosas. Saludos

```js
var nextinput = 0;


function AgregarCampos() {
  nextinput++;
  var content = '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-xs-5">' +
      '<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-xs-5">' +
      '<input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="campo" name="valores" placeholder="Ingrese el valor" />' +   '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-xs-2">' +
      '<button type="button">-</button>' +  
    '</div>' +
  '</div>';
  
  $("#campos").append(content);
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.row').remove();
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input onclick="AgregarCampos();" type="button" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-primary" />
</p>
<div id="campos">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en que tienes el `input` como hijo de `#campos` al hacer `$(this).parent().remove()` eliminas el `id #campos` y por eso ya no se agregaban más. Hice unas modificaciones a tu código:

La variable `campo` de la función la deje de esta forma:

```
var campo = '' +
'<div class="row">' +
  '<div class="col-xs-4">' +
    '<p><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="campo" name="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" /></p>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="col-xs-4">' +
    '<input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="campo" name="valores" placeholder="Ingrese el valor" />' +
  '</div>'+
  '<input type="button" class="remove" value="-" />'+
'</div>';
```

metiendo el botón para eliminar al padre tal como lo quieres tu.
Después cree una función para detectar el `click` del botón:

```
$('#campos').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  //console.log(this);
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Te dejo tu código funcionando:

```js
var nextinput = 0;

function AgregarCampos() {
  nextinput++;
  var campo = '' +
    '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col-xs-4">' +
        '<p><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="campo" name="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" /></p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="col-xs-4">' +
        '<input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="campo" name="valores" placeholder="Ingrese el valor" />' +
      '</div>'+
      '<input type="button" class="remove" value="-" />'+
    '</div>';
  $("#campos").append(campo);
}

$('#campos').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  //console.log(this);
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input onclick="AgregarCampos();" type="button" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-primary" />
</p>
<div id="campos">
</div>
```